# Jquery / PHP Scroll to as page updates?

Tags: php, jquery, scroll, load

I'm using the following to run a command and output it's data as it proceeds.

```
$a = popen('command to run...', 'r');

while($b = fgets($a, 2048)) {
    echo "$b<br/>";
    ob_flush();flush();
}
```

This works fine, but I'd like my page to scroll down each time a new line is echo'd to screen.

Any idea how I can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
$a = popen('command to run...', 'r');

while($b = fgets($a, 2048)) {
    echo "$b<br/>";
    echo "<script>
          setTimeout(function() { 
                      var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                      $(window).scrollTop(scrollBottom);}
                    ,100);
          </script>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how are you updating the page, but for scrolling, you can do it like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

where `elementtoScrollToID` is the ID of new element added on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It would be dirty but you can try this:

```
$a = popen('command to run...', 'r');

while($b = fgets($a, 2048)) {
    echo "$b<br/>";
    echo "<script>
          $('body').animate({
              'scrollTop': $(document).height()
          }); 
          </script>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```